# Why is mutable specifier classified to be storage class specifier, but not a qualifier?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, language-design, mutable, storage-class-specifier

When the `mutable` specifier is used in the  declaration of a non-static data member, the data is mutable no matter whether the rest of the object is treated as const. With this fact, we may easily have the impression that `mutable` specifier is the same kind of thing as the `const` qualifier, which turns out to be not true. In fact, the language classifies `mutable` specifier as a storage class specifier. This is quite counter-intuitive because `mutable` does not specifies storage duration.

What are the rationales behind this design decision?

What would make it less logical than it would seemed if `mutable` was a qualifier?

What are the advantages of making it a storage class specifier?

Comment: Your question is directly answered in [dcl.stc] of N4140: `The mutable specifier on a class data member nullifies a const specifier applied to the containing class object and permits modification of the mutable class member even though the rest of the object is const (7.1.6.1).`

Comment: `const` and `volatile` are part of the type. `mutable` isn't.

Comment: An implementation is permitted to put a const object in read only memory - but not the mutable members, obviously. So if you squint a bit it is not totally unrelated to storage.

Comment: @user6292850 No, it does not, utterly not.

Comment: `const` applies differently to each 'level' when there is indirection in the type, but `mutable` is always "top-level".  And it's nice to allow `mutable int *p;` instead of requiring `int * mutable p;`

Answer (score 11):

*cv-qualifier*s modify/restrict the object's semantics; `mutable` does not. It being part of the type would be superfluous in practically all scenarios, while necessitating more paragraphs about pointer conversions etc.

Thus it was decided to make it a *decl-specifier* that isn't a *type-specifier*. Since `const` can cause an object to be put into write-protected memory, `mutable` can cause an object not to be put into such storage, suggesting it is a *storage-class-specifier*.

Comment: I suppose a hypothetical `mutable int C::*` (with `mutable` being part of the type pointed to) could be used to change a `const C` object's mutable `int` subobject via the pointer-to-member syntax, but certainly the cost is far greater than the benefit.